# Image resizeMode requires other style properties

Tags: react-native

I have resizeMode on an Image working, but don't understand why some lines are required.  Why are the lines below with the comment "// why?" required to get the resizeMode value to be honored? Removing any of those breaks it.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const Images = () =>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      source={require('./giraffes.jpg')}
      style={styles.myImage}/>
  </View>;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1 // to fill screen
  },
  myImage: {
    flex: 1, // why?
    resizeMode: 'contain', // can also use Image.resizeMode.contain
    height: null, // why?
    width: null // why?
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Images', () => Images);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `flex: 1` because `resizeMode` is used to resize depending on the outer container. Since the outer container has a `flex` value of `1`, when you put `flex:1` on `myImage`, you're telling it that you want it to fill up 1/1, aka the whole outer container. Using `null` on the `height` and `width` overrides the default fixed static size of the image.